# React Routing "Cannot GET /" with Parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am new to React and trying to use parameter with the react-dom-router. But every time i'm trying to call the URL with the parameter, i always get the 'Cannot GET /...' Error.

This is my index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from "./app";

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
}
```

And this is my app.js

```js
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link, useParams} from "react-router-dom"
import Profile from "./pages/Profile/Profile";
import About from "./pages/About/About";

const App = () => (
  <Fragment>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/:profile" component={Profile} />
        <Route path="/" component={About} />
    </Switch>
  </Fragment>
);

export default App;
```

Comment: Would this question be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

Comment: Do you really need a parameter? If not just get rid of the :  so your route would be just /profile

Comment: Yes i really need a parameter. I would like to render the profile page with different data. The awensered are not helpful for this question.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by adding following to the webpack config:

```json
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
```